# com.android.dex.DexException: Multiple dex files define Lcom/google/android/gms/internal/config/zzao;

Tags: android, cordova, android-studio, ionic-framework

I've come across this issue at random points when building my ionic-cordova app, normally forcing the removal and reinstallation of `cordova-plugin-compat@1.2.0` would fix the issue and get me up and running again but this time it is not the case.

I have not made any changes to code or plugins since I was last able to successfully run the android platform so I am not sure where this error would be coming from. A co-worker of mine is on the exact same code and is able to build just fine so it doesn't make sense how it would just show up out of the blue.

Any help would be great

Comment: Have you tried using Cordova-clean to clean your project?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Running the following commands in that order fixed the issue for me:

```
cordova plugin rm cordova-plugin-compat --force --save
cordova plugin add cordova-plugin-compat@1.2 --save
rm -rf ~/.gradle/caches/*
cd platforms/android -> gradlew clean
```